# Textbox not showing inserts in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import time


def centertitle(e):
    w = int(root.winfo_width() / 3.5)
    s = 'Installation Wizard v1.0'.rjust(w//2)
    root.title(s)

def textbox():
    textbox=Text(root.canvas, width = 62, height = 25, state=DISABLED)
    textbox.pack()
    textbox.insert(constants.INSERT,'You text goes here')

#Configure tkinter window and title
root = Tk()
root.canvas = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 404, bg="#3D3D3D", highlightthickness=0)
root.canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

root.iconbitmap(default='transparent.ico')  
root.bind("<Configure>", centertitle)
root.resizable(False, False)

#Buttons
btn = tk.Button(root, text='Start Install', height = 2, width = 15)
btn['command'] =  lambda b=btn:[b.pack_forget(), b.place_forget(), textbox()]
btn.pack(fill=BOTH)
btn.place(x=190, y=181)

root.mainloop()
```

What im trying to create, is a simple "install" gui, which i was gonna pack into an exe. all i really want is a button, that starts another python file (the one that installs everything) and when it calls print, i want it sent to the text box in the gui... its hard to explain but i hope you get what i mean

could someone help me im really confused with guis

code from other .py:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
import subprocess;
from pathlib import Path
import psutil
import time


def startProgram(program):
    SW_HIDE = 0
    info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    info.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    info.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
    subprocess.Popen(program, startupinfo=info)
    
def terminateProgram(processName):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if processName.lower() in proc.name().lower():
            proc.terminate()
           
def checkIfProcessRunning(processName):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            if processName.lower() in proc.name().lower():
                return True
        except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
            pass
    return False;

st_inf = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
st_inf.dwFlags = st_inf.dwFlags | subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
user_profile = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
appdata_local = os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA']
FolderDictionary = [(user_profile + '\spicetify-cli'), (user_profile + '\.spicetify'), (appdata_local + '\spotify')]

for x in FolderDictionary:
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(x)
        print('"%s", has been deleted.\n' % x)
    except OSError as e :
        print('"%s", was not found.\n' % x)
        
print("Installing Spotify.\n")
terminateProgram('Spotify.exe')
startProgram('.\\data\spotify-1-1-62-583.exe')
while True:
    if checkIfProcessRunning('spotify-1-1-62-583.exe') == False:
        print("Finished Installing Spotify.\n")
        terminateProgram('Spotify.exe')
        break

print("Installing Spicetify.\n")
terminateProgram('powershell')
subprocess.Popen(["powershell","$v='2.5.0'; Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khanhas/spicetify-cli/master/install.ps1' | Invoke-Expression\nspicetify\nspicetify backup apply enable-devtool"], startupinfo=st_inf)
while True:
    if checkIfProcessRunning('powershell') == False:
        print("Finished Installing Spicetify.\n")
        terminateProgram('Spotify.exe')
        break

print("Downloading Themes.\n")
terminateProgram('powershell')
subprocess.Popen(["powershell",'$sp_dir = "${HOME}\spicetify-cli"\n$zip_file = "${sp_dir}\Themes.zip"\n$download_uri = "https://github.com/morpheusthewhite/spicetify-themes/archive/refs/heads/v2.zip"\nInvoke-WebRequest -Uri $download_uri -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $zip_file\nExpand-Archive -Path $zip_file -DestinationPath $sp_dir -Force\nRemove-Item -Path $zip_file\nRemove-Item -LiteralPath "${HOME}\spicetify-cli\Themes" -Force -Recurse\nRename-Item "${HOME}\spicetify-cli\spicetify-themes-2" "${HOME}\spicetify-cli\Themes"\nRemove-Item "${HOME}\spicetify-cli\Themes\*.*" -Force -Recurse | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }\nRename-Item "${HOME}\spicetify-cli\Themes\default" "${HOME}\spicetify-cli\Themes\SpicetifyDefault"'], startupinfo=st_inf) 
while True:
    if checkIfProcessRunning('powershell') == False:
        print("Finished Downloading Themes.\n")
        break
```

Comment: Why are there two blocks of code? What is the purpose of `other.py`? It's not referenced by the first block of code. Please try to have only a single block of code to avoid confusion.

Comment: Why are you putting the `Text` widget inside the `Canvas`? Also while the `state` of the `Text` widget is `"disabled"`, no one can't edit it's contents. That includes you. Use `.config(state="normal")` then try to insert your text

Answer (score 1):

You've set the state of the text widget to disabled, so you can't insert anything into it. If you want it to be disabled, disable it after inserting the text rather than before.

```
def textbox():
    textbox=Text(root.canvas, width = 62, height = 25)
    textbox.pack()
    textbox.insert(constants.INSERT,'You text goes here')
    textbox.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Textbox not showing inserts in tkinter

The problem can be fixed.

You're having typo error `textbox.insert(constants.INSERT, ..` should be `textbox.insert(tk.INSERT, ...`

You can, however, use `Tk.END` or `0`

```
def textbox():
    textbox=Text(root.canvas, width = 62, height = 25)
    textbox.pack()
    textbox.insert(tk.INSERT,'You text goes here')
    textbox.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

Screenshot:

[image]